# How to speed up Copy Paste Values when using Offset

Tags: excel, vba

I want make this basic function of "*copy&paste-values-on-a-new-row-each-time*" run as fast as possible since the macro repeats the calculations hundreds of thousands of times. I just can't find the exact answer after searching this forum for ages.

Currently, I'm copying output numbers from a fixed range and, elsewhere on the worksheet, pasting the values on a new row for each new set of results.

Here's the portion of the code doing this:

```
Row = Row +1
Range("g15:ax15").copy
Range("ea18").select
ActiveCell.Offset(Row,0).select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Now from what I have found on this forum, I can replace the Copy/Paste functions completely with `Range(destination).value = Range(results).value` to speed things up. However, I can't figure out how to do this if the destination rows need to be offset by 1 each time. Also, I've read that one could even do away with "select" to speed things up further! How?

Comment: **Q1:** You always copy the row 15 (*"g15:ax15"*) ? Or this is should also offset by 1 every itineration? **Q2:** Do you know whole (all) range(s) you want to copy before the copy operation? You can copy paste whole range instead of one row at a time.

Comment: You guys are fantastic!  That's plenty for me to experiment with.  Thanks a million everyone for the quick and detailed replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options:

```
//This uses the `Destination` key word
Sub CopyAndPaste()
    Dim i as long
    For i = 1 to 10
        Range("g15:ax15").Copy Destination:=Range("ea18").Offset(i, 0)
    next i
End Sub

//If you need `PasteSpecial` then you cannot use `Destination` hence this version
Sub CopyAndPaste()
    Dim i as long
    For i = 1 to 10
        Range("g15:ax15").Copy
        Range("ea18").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    next i
End Sub
```

Sometimes reading values into an array first and then writing back to the spreadsheet is quicker. Here is an example:

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()
    Dim i As Long, numbers As Variant, rw As Long

    numbers = Range("g15:ax15")
    rw = 18

    For i = 1 To 10
        rw = rw + 1
        Range(Cells(rw, 131), Cells(rw, 131 + UBound(numbers, 2) - 1)) = numbers
    Next i    
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without copying as yo mention (using a variant array as you are copying values only, not formats)

```
X = Range("g15:ax15").Value2
[ea18].Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X
```

or with your variable offset

```
Dim lngCnt As Long
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
X = Range("g15:ax15").Value2
[ea18].Offset(lngCnt, 0).Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Row = Row +1
 Range("g15:ax15").copy
 Range("ea18").Offset(Row,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Select is a more-or-less useless method inherited from recordings.